# Deleting Datagridview rows using LOOP

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

My Data Grid View Contains One Column.
Many Rows of `DataGridView` are empty I am using Loop to remove those rows.

```
For j = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1           
    If DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value.ToString.Length = 0 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(j)
    End If
Next
```

> **Error** : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the
>   size of the collection.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike C#, in VB.NET the For loop upper bound is evaluated [only once in the beginning of the loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement#parts), and is not re-evaluated in each loop iteration. You can loop from the last row to avoid the issue(s):

```
For j = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If DataGridView1(0, j).Value = "" Then DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(j)
Next
```